# Why is the sum infinite fractions not infinite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How can I show the following?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2<\infty$$

Isn't it:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{\infty}\right)^2=\infty$$

Comment: See [Bassel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)

Comment: The term $1/\infty$ is wrong, because it never appears in the sum.

Comment: Note:  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\ne\infty$ too

Comment: On the note of J.W.Tanner: You can easily see this by taking a piece of paper, splitting it in half, splitting one half in half again and so on. You should even be able to guess what the limit will be :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the same argument with $$S=\sum_{i=}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^\infty}$$ But it is clear from the picture below that $S=1$.

[image]

Also, in your case it is increasing and bounded by $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k ^ 2} \lt 1 + \sum_{k=2}^n \frac 1  {k (k - 1)} = 2 - \frac 1 n \lt 2$$ and therefore converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$S_N=\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{1}{k^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}-\psi'(N+1)$$ where $\psi'$ is the first derivative of the digamma function. Because 
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}\psi'(N+1)=0,$$
$S_N \to \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the terms of the sum decrease quickly enough the sum will converge to a finite limit.  An easier one to sum is 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^i}$$  The definition of an infinite sum is to make the upper limit $n$, then take the limit as $n \to \infty$.  If the limit converges, that is the sum of the series.  In this case
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{2^i}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac 1{2^n}\right)=1$$
In your expression the sum also converges, but proving the limit is harder.